# Query to plot a histogram of song ratings

Tags: php, mysql, statistics, pdo, data-visualization

I wrote code to plot a rating distribution, which looks like this:

[image]

The most important function is the `stats` function:

```
function stats($songID){
    $st=$this->conn->prepare("SELECT
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE SongID=:songID),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE SongID=:songID AND Rating='10'),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE SongID=:songID AND Rating='9.5'),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE SongID=:songID AND Rating='9'),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE SongID=:songID AND Rating='8.5'),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE SongID=:songID AND Rating='8'),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE SongID=:songID AND Rating='7.5'),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE SongID=:songID AND Rating='7'),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE SongID=:songID AND Rating='6.5'),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE SongID=:songID AND Rating='6'),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE SongID=:songID AND Rating='5.5'),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE SongID=:songID AND Rating='5'),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE SongID=:songID AND Rating='4.5'),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE SongID=:songID AND Rating='4'),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE SongID=:songID AND Rating='3.5'),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE SongID=:songID AND Rating='3'),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE SongID=:songID AND Rating='2.5'),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE SongID=:songID AND Rating='2'),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE SongID=:songID AND Rating='1.5'),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE SongID=:songID AND Rating='1'),
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE SongID=:songID AND Rating='0.5')
        FROM list WHERE SongID=:songID");
    $st->bindparam(":songID",$songID);
    $st->execute();
    return $st->fetchall();
}


function bars($rate,$percentage,$ratings){
    return <<<HTML
    <div class="progress border border-dark w-100 bg-transparent border-0 mt-1">
            <span style="width:20px;" class="font-weight-bold text-light">
                {$rate}
            </span>
            <div class="progress-bar border border-dark bg-light" role="progressbar" style="max-width:25%;width:{$percentage}%;" aria-valuenow="{$ratings}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
            <span class="font-weight-bold text-light ml-1 mr-1">
                {$percentage}%({$ratings} votes)
            </span>
        </div>
HTML;
}
```

And then in another file I use these methods:

```
$stats=$song->stats($_GET['songid']);
    foreach($stats as $key){
        $total=$key[0];
        $rate=10;
        for($i=1;$i<21;$i++){
            echo $song->bars($rate,round(($key[$i]/$total)*100,2),$key[$i]);
            $rate-=0.5;
            }
            break;
        }
```

This code works perfectly, but somehow I'm not satisfied with the `stats` function, the way I solved it. It's just too long, and doesn't look quite good to me.

So the question is: is there a way to make that `function` a bit shorter, so I wouldn't repeat the same thing 20 times but with different values for the `Rating` column?

I was thinking that this might actually be the only way to do it, but I thought I'd give it a try here, since there are way smarter programmers here than I am.

Comment: Just to make the question clear, please post the schema definition for the `list` table as well.

Answer (score 6):

It would be better to use GROUP by in your SQL. By this way you will get rid of long SQL query.

```
SELECT Rating, COUNT(id) FROM list WHERE songID=:songID GROUP BY Rating;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are trying to extract ALL of the rating values from your table, I agree with Unnamed that you should simply GROUP BY and return the `Rating`, and the `COUNT()` in the result set.

Two things to add here...

1. Without apply default values, you need to be aware that Unnamed's query will potentially deliver gaps where there is no count for a particular `Rating` score.  To mitigate this, you should `array_merge()` your own set of defaults (all of the expected Rating scores) and assign them with a zero count or modify your looping process to provide 0 counts for missing Ratings.
2. `GROUP BY` has a cool feature that will provide the grand total for you as well (which seems perfect for your use case and is not included in unnamed's solution)-- `ROLL UP`: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-rollup/

   This means you can do something like:

   ```
   function stats($songID){
       $st = $this->conn->prepare(
           "SELECT COALESCE(Rating, 'Total') Rating, COUNT(1) `Count`
            FROM list
            WHERE songID = ?
            GROUP BY Rating DESC WITH ROLLUP"
       );

       return $st->execute([$songID])->fetchall();
   }
   ```

   Here's a fiddle demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9WZJwBunnEHjy6MMQGYSbt/4